# Import Error in installation: Error installing Horovod and Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install Tensorflow and Horovod

```
pip install tensorflow

HOROVOD_WITH_TENSORFLOW=1 pip install horovod
```

Then I ran a sample code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import horovod.tensorflow as hvd
```

When I run this code, I get the error

```
ImportError: Extension horovod.tensorflow has not been built.  If this is not expected, reinstall Horovod with HOROVOD_WITH_TENSORFLOW=1 to debug the build error.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to install tensorflow and horovod , you can use the following steps:

1)Create a conda environment to avoid the mismatch of package versions.

```
conda create -n test_hvd -c intel python=3.6
```

2)Activate the environment

```
source activate test_hvd
```

(You can use any name instead of **test_hvd**, which is an environment name.)

3)Install tensorflow in the activated environment:

```
pip install  https://storage.googleapis.com/intel-optimized-tensorflow/tensorflow-1.10.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

4)Finally install horovod

```
pip install --no-cache-dir horovod
```

Note: 1. Kindly confirm if you are using the latest versions of GCC (gcc (GCC) 6.4.0 works fine).

2. These steps are tested on Linux OS

Hope this helps!